# Overestimate of $|\oint_{|z|=R} f(z) \mathrm{d}z|$ with $f(z)=\frac{z^a}{z^2+1}$, $0<|a|<1\mathrm{with} \;a \in \mathbb R$

Tags: complex-analysis, estimation, parameter-estimation

How can I overestimate, $|\oint_{|z|=R} f(z) \mathrm{d}z |$ with $f(z)=\frac{z^a}{z^2+1}$, $0<|a|<1 \; \mathrm{with} \;a \in \mathbb R$ ?

I tried this:
$|\oint_{|z|=R} f(z) \mathrm{d}z | <= \mathrm{length \;curve \times maximum\; modulus}$ =$2\pi R\times M $.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to find $M$.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Use reverse triangle inequality on the denominator,intuitively the +1 is negligible for large $R$

Comment: How do you define $z^a$ if $z$ is any complex number of modulus $R$?

Comment: @PhilippeMalot $a\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I see, that's quite different. You should modify your question, then.

Comment: $z^a$ is not uniquely defined for non integer $a$

Comment: @Evan  Triangle inequality: $|z^2+1| =||z^2| +|1| | >= |z^2-1| >=| |z^2 | -| 1| |$. Do you mean this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\left|z\right|=R$, then, since $a$ is a real number :

$$\left|\dfrac{z^a}{z^2+1}\right|=\dfrac{\left|z^a\right|}{\left|z^2+1\right|}=\dfrac{R^a}{\left|z^2+1\right|}$$

Now, following Evan's indication, for all $z\in\mathbb C$ :

$$\left|z^2+1\right|\geqslant\left|\left|z^2\right|-1\right|\geqslant\left|z^2\right|-1=\left|z\right|^2-1$$

For $\left|z\right|=R$, you get :

$$\left|z^2+1\right|\geqslant R^2-1$$

If $R>1$ and $\left|z\right|=R$, you can invert both sides, reversing the inequality :

$$\dfrac 1{\left|z^2+1\right|}\leqslant \dfrac 1{R^2-1}$$

From there, you can easily find your $M$.

Comment: Now, assume that I would have had ln(z) in the numerator instead of $z^a$, would I then need to treat numerator and denominator separately and use the triangle inequality for each?